# Sending parameters to EF Core SqlQuery

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

Is sending parameters like this with `SqlQuery` safe against SQL injection?

```cs
var page_param = new SqlParameter("page_param", page);
var pageSize_param = new SqlParameter("pageSize_param", pageSize);

var users = _context!.Database.SqlQuery<UserDTO>($"SELECT u.Id,u.FirstName,u.LastName,u.JoinDate,u.UserName,u.Email,u.EmailConfirmed,u.PhoneNumber,r.Name as Role FROM Users as u inner join UserRoles as ur on u.Id = ur.UserId inner join Roles r on ur.RoleId = r.Id order by u.JoinDate OFFSET {page_param} ROWS FETCH NEXT {pageSize_param} ROWS ONLY ");
```

I want to write secure SQL query

Comment: Why don't you use EF Core as an ORM? DbContext isn't a database connection or driver, it's a multi-entity Unit-of-Work. You can replace this query with `_contest.Uses.Include(u=>u.Roles).OrderBy(u=>u.JoinDate).Skip(10).Take(10)`. EF will generate a query similar to your own, using entity relations to generate JOINs as needed

Comment: I have 2 contexts. They are located in Users Identity.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation of [SqlQuery-Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.sqlquery?view=efcore-8.0#remarks)

> Any parameter values you supply will automatically be converted to a DbParameter.

So, yes it is safe. And you can pass just integers ans strings without using `SqlParameter`.

Note that, for such simple queries better to use LINQ.

Comment: As long as you use `SqlQuery` not `SqlQueryRaw`

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will take it into consideration.